# CircleCI deploy to AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, yaml, circleci

I can't find any good and understandable examples of a CircleCI config to build and deploy to an AWS EC2 instance. Here's what I have so far:

**.circleci/config.yml**

```
version: 2
jobs:
    build:
        docker:
            - image: circleci/node:10.7
        steps:
            - checkout
            - restore_cache:
                keys:
                    - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
                    - v1-dependencies-
            - run:
                name: Install dependencies
                command: npm install
            - save_cache:
                key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
                paths:
                    - node_modules
            - run:
                name: Lint code
                command: npm run lint
            - run:
                name: Build app
                command: npm run build
            - save_cache:
                key: v1-build-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_BRANCH }}-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_SHA1 }}
                paths:
                    - .next
    deploy:
        docker:
            - image: circleci/node:10.7
        steps:
            - run:
                name: Deploy production
                command: ?
workflows:
    version: 2
    build_and_deploy:
        jobs:
            - build
            - deploy:
                requires:
                    - build
```

So far, the entire build step works perfectly, which moves onto the deployment step successfully. But how do I deploy the the build to a folder on my EC2 server when the branch being built is `master`?

Comment: What do you mean by deploy the build to a folder on EC2? Is this referring to `scp` -ing something to the EC2 instance? Or running the `node` app in something like pm2 or Docker?

Comment: Or is it only a matter of conditionally running a command depending on the git branch?

Comment: @JackGore Yes I'd like to run the app on my EC2 instance. Currently I've only got as far as a successful build in CircleCI.

Comment: Currently I can do a local production build, scp the files to my EC2 instance, SSH into EC2 and launch the app with PM2. I'm trying to automate the full deployment process. I'm surprised there doesn't seem to be any good examples/tutorials of this online because I assumed this would be extremely common.

Comment: any update on this? I'm in the same boat

Comment: Any workaround for this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68029679/circleci-ssh-permission-denied-publickey-on-ec2-from-circleci-build

Answer (score 0):

From [this article](https://medium.com/@Sayadi/how-to-ssh-to-an-aws-ec2-instance-running-linux-from-a-circleci-build-fffa45003715), you can use this config.yml setup:

```
version: 2
general:
  branches:
    only:
      - dev
      - staging
      - prod
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Deploy
          command: |
            # 1- Install AWS CLI
            curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
            unzip awscli-bundle.zip
            ./awscli-bundle/install -b ~/bin/aws
            # 2- Get the public IP of the current CircleCI runner
            PUBLIC_IP=$(curl ipinfo.io/ip)
            # 3- Get AWS Region# TODO Don't forget to replcae by your own Region
            AWS_REGION=us-east-2
            # 4- Get SG ID# TODO Don't forget to replace by your own SG ID
            SG_ID=sg-XXXXXXXX
            # 5- Add an ingress rule to the security group
            ~/bin/aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --region $AWS_REGION --group-id $SG_ID \
              --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr $PUBLIC_IP/24
            # 6- Give the ingress rule some time to propogate
            sleep 5
            # 7- SSH to the server to deploy
            # TODO Change to your username
            EC2_USERNAME=ubuntu
            # TODO Change to your server's URL or public IP
            EC2_PUBLIC_DNS=application-server.example.com
            ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $EC2_USERNAME@$EC2_PUBLIC_DNS \
            # other commands
            # TODO Perform steps to deploy
            # .
            # .
            # .
            # 8- Remove the ingress rule
            ~/bin/aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --region $AWS_REGION --group-id $SG_ID \
              --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr $PUBLIC_IP/24
```